# What is the literal meaning of "Hau ab!"?

Tags: phrase, expression, etymology

If you want to tell somebody to go away you could shout:

> ***"Hau ab!"***

However this is considered as not very polite, much like *"Get lost!"*, or *"F`***` off!"*. I am wondering where German *"Hau ab"* comes from to explain why it is considered as rude in usage. What does it mean literally?

Comment: The *literal* meaning, obtained when you analyse the verb and translate the two constituents literally while taking context into account, is simply *beat off*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

"Hau ab!" is the imperative of [*abhauen*](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abhauen#Bedeutung3), which has the colloquial meaning (among others) of *to escape quickly*.

The Duden derives it from *hauen*, which means *to beat* and is said to refer to beating a horse with the spurs on your boots. [Grimm's dictionary](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GH03355#XGH03355) still mentions the meaning *to hurry*, *to run* for *hauen* and gives the same reasoning:

> **13)** hauen *endlich für eilen, streben, laufen. diese bedeutung hat wol ihren ausgang von dem einhauen der sporen in des rosses weichen*

Together with the prefix *ab-* (off, away) you get *to run away*, *to get off quickly*.

But note that this old meaning of *hauen* is no longer present, and Grimm's doesn't say *abhauen* to mean *to escape*. If they didn't miss it, the verb must have derived this meaning after this part of the dictionary was written, but before *hauen* lost its meaning of *to hurry*.

This gives room to a second theory: according to the book [Westjiddisches Wörterbuch](https://books.google.de/books?id=Kcy_D3HtY2AC&pg=PA247&lpg=PA247&dq=abhauen+rotwelsch&source=bl&ots=DV_txCsyFR&sig=TBrH_jmLX-4IqpStD5yiyQxmVT8&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0CDEQ6AEwA2oVChMI1PPHzIKJyAIVStYsCh1GjwvT#v=onepage&q=abhauen%20rotwelsch&f=false), the verb *abhauen* might derive from *abbauen*, which is [Rotwelsch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotwelsch) for *to escape*, *to flee* and has Yiddish origins. It is further said to have a Hebrew root that means *to come*.

A Rotwelsch, i.e. thieve's argot, origin might also have contributed to the derogative touch of *abhauen*, which in turn can also explain (to some degree at least) why "Hau ab" sounds rather rude, as you mention in your question.

Comment: Is it safe to assume that Grimm is only guessing?

Answer (score 22):

According to [this link](http://www.heinrich-tischner.de/22-sp/2wo/wort/idg/deutsch/a/abhauen.htm), *hauen* used to mean "hurry" or "run" at some point in addition to "beat", probably originating from "beating a horse to make it run faster". "Ab" is a Latin prefix meaning "away from."

So "abhauen" just means "run away".

I don't think it's rude because of its etymology, but because there are very few polite ways to tell someone to go away in general, because a) you're telling someone what to do, and b) you're telling them "I don't want you here." That's going to come across as impolite pretty much regardless of what words you use.

I don't think "Hau ab!" is any more impolite than "Go away!" "F**k off!" is stronger than that, and a better German equivalent would be "Verpiss dich!"

Comment: Nice explanation. "*Hau ab"* definitely is stronger than *"Geh weg"*. *"Verpiss Dich"* is used regionally (but less so recently).

Comment: I agree that it's stronger than "Geh weg", but I'd say "Go away" is still a pretty good translation. English doesn't seem to have as many nuanced ways to tell someone to leave. It goes directly from "Go away" to various vulgarities.

Comment: But why *"ab"* and not "*weg"*?

Comment: +1 for pointing out that "Hau ab" has not to be impolite. For example "Hau ab" is also somthing you could say to a fugitive if the "bad guys" come to get him.

Comment: @Takkat "Hau weg" means something completely different: http://www.redensarten-index.de/suche.php?suchbegriff=~~Hau%20weg%20%28z.B.%20den%20Scheiss%2C%20das%20Zeug%29&bool=relevanz&suchspalte[]=rart_ou

Comment: @starblue: much like *"Hau ruck"* is different too ;). Still, if *hauen* means *to run* the usage of prefix (or preposition) *ab* seems not to fit. *"Hau fort"* does not exist.

Comment: @Takkat: edited my answer, hope that clears it up. Now why this particular word has a Latin prefix and not a Germanic one, I don't know either.

Comment: @Cass: after some research I found that as ***"ab"*** may be similar to Latin (*ab*) or Greek (*ἀπό*) it may in fact most likely be of Germanic (*aҍa*) or Gothic (*af*) origin.

Comment: Don't forget: `Hau ser` ;)

Comment: Actually, (at least) in Swiss german, one can say `ich haus jetzt`, meaning `I leave now` (without any emotional connotation)

Comment: @Cass: There are plenty of English alternatives to “go away” before you get to the vulgar stuff: “get lost”, “on your bike”, “beat it”, “scram”, “trot on”…

Comment: "ab" is definitely not Latin in this context, but a German prefix I'd usually translate as "off". Compare also "abtreten", which can mean "to leave the stage" (theater).

Comment: Probably from "beating the road" while running.

Comment: @starblue "sich weghauen" can be understood as *to go to bed*, cp. *sich hinauen*. In the sense *to laugh ones ass off* the figurative rolling *on the floor* is a given.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis do you mean "Ich hau's, haue es" or "hausen", from "Haus"?

Comment: @vectory: hauen = to beat. Guess what I mean.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis I don't know what you mean. I asked a straight question. Perhaps you mean [bet](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Semitic/bayt-)? hauen = to hew, by the way, depending on what kind of congruence relation you choose.

Comment: @vectory: I mean **beat**. And **hauen**. What is there not to understand? **Hauen** is the German verb for **to beat**. I do not mean **bet**, I do not mean **Haus** or **Hau's**. I hope that is clear enough? I guess the word **abhauen** comes from the German equivalent of "hitting/beating the road".

Comment: @RenéNyffenegger Das war eigentlich an dich gerichtet

Comment: @RudyVelthuis sorry. Anyhow, that doesn't really figure because one wouldn't say "die Straße hauen", erst recht nicht "Die Straße abhauen"? "hit the road" comes to mind, but that means to go on a journey, not to go home, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1):

Hau ab, this comes from the verb *abhauen*, that's a word for "to run away".

Answer (score 0):

The more appropriate translation appears to be, “beat it.”